# Connecting to Sharepoint Via Python - UrlLib Error

Tags: python-3.x, sharepoint, urllib, ntlm

The following code (with variables changed) is what I am trying to use in order to contact a sharepoint server (and ultimately download files from). But I appear to be getting an error related to urllib, for which I can't work out the reason for.

```
from sharepoint import SharePointSite, basic_auth_opener
server_url = "http://sharepoint.domain.com/"
opener = basic_auth_opener(server_url, "domain/username", "password")
site = SharePointSite(server_url, opener)
sp_list = site.lists
for sp_list in site.lists:
    print(sp_list.id, sp_list.meta['Title'])
```

The error is as follows

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try with below code

```
import requests from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth
requests.get("http://sharepoint.domain.com", auth=HttpNtlmAuth('DOMAIN\\USERNAME','PASSWORD'))
```

Comment: requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='sharepoint.example.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001CC8073F2B0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond',))

Comment: I'm assuming at this point it's a networking issue of some sort.

Comment: Yes and also double check the SP site URL